# awk: find matching pattern1 in file containg pattern2

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I am parsing plenty of files and searching for correspondences with awk.
I am stuck searching for a way to find the file containing pattern1 and search pattern2 only in this file.

example:

```
file1:  
text xyz 122e345a rxyc  
abc 25b57790c

file 2:  
text tio 36e79a89 opgb  
abc b0894e35o  

file 3:  
text diowps aaaacc  
abc 122e345a
```

What I want as result should be:

```
25b57790c
```

While the first pattern that I have is:

```
122e345a
```

The only solution I had for now was to do it in 2 steps:

```
FILE=$(awk '$3 == "122e345a" {print FILENAME}' * )  
awk '$1 == "abc" {print $2}' $FILE
```

I can have a one liner like this one:

```
awk '$1 == "abc" {print $2}' $(awk '$3 == "122e345a" {print FILENAME}' * )
```

But I would like to avoid the double awk call, can't it be done in one single awk command?

Comment: An excellent first Q. Keep posting! (but *use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output.*. Good luck.

Comment: The word "pattern" is ambiguous and should be avoided. To clarify your question - replace the word "pattern" with "string" or "regexp" everywhere it occurs, whichever one you really mean at each point, and state if the matching should be full or partial. It LOOKS from your scripts like what you're trying to do is string matching on full strings but we can't be sure what you want from a script that doesn't do what you want. You currently have 2 answers - one using full string matching and the other partial regexp matching so it'll save time if you just state which you actually need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file != FILENAME       { found = 0 }
         $3 == a       { found = 1; file = FILENAME }
found && $1 == b       { print $2  }
```

or, for GNU `awk`:

```
BEGINFILE              { found = 0 }
         $3 == a       { found = 1 }
found && $1 == b       { print $2  }
```

This is very similar to markp's solution (and makes similar assumptions), but may be run on any number of input files without the use of a shell loop:

```
$ awk -f script.awk a="122e345a" b="abc" file[123]
25b57790c
```

The script(s) also assumes that the patterns that you'd like to search for are actually fixed strings in specific columns (as indicated by the question).

Since there's no way of "rewinding" a file in `awk`, you need to pass over the file twice if you want to find the second string *before* the first string. The code at the end of the question itself is a solution for that.

Alternatively, you may save the whole file in a variable and go through that once you find the first string (that solution not included here).

Comment: the first script give no result, and the second one don't really work as expected.
It prints second argument when pattern b is matched on all files parsed after the correct file, this one not included.

Comment: @luxfred Then you have either left something out of the description of the problem, or you are failing to run the script properly. Both scripts work with GNU Awk, and the first script works with GNU Awk, Mawk and BSD Awk, regardless of the ordering of the input files (the three files in the text of the question).

Comment: I check again, the problem was my file was wrong second pattern was showing before fist one.  
The second script reports all files starting with the one matching the first pattern   
But the first one does exactly the trick I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note: Updated to show complete match on the desired patterns; if the objective is to show partial matches then replace the search patterns accordingly:

```
partial matching:  $3 ~ /122e345a/
                   $1 ~ /abc/

complete matching: $3 == "122e345a"
                   $1 == "abc"
```

---

Assumptions:

- the first search consists of looking for a line where the third field is a complete match for the string `"122e345a"`, and if found then ...
- look for a line where the first field is a complete match for the string `"abc"`, and if found then ...
- print the contents of the second field (of the line that contains string `"abc"`)
- the string `"122e345a"` appears first in the file, with the string `"abc"` showing up either a) in the same line as the first string or b) in a subsequent line
- if string `"abc"` shows up multiple times in a file (after string `"122e345a"` is found), then each occurrence of string `"abc"` will cause a `print` command to be issued

One possible `awk` solution:

```
awk '
BEGIN                            { found = 0 }
                $3 == "122e345a" { found = 1 }
(found == 1) && $1 == "abc"      { print $2  }
' <file>
```

- set variable `found=0`; since this is part of the `BEGIN` block it is only performed at the beginning of processing a new file (ie, we're initializing `found`)
- if the string `"122e345a"` is found in the 3rd field of a line then set `found = 1`
- if our variable `found` is set to `1`, and string `"abc"` is found in the first field of a line, then print the second field of that line

NOTE: You can submit the awk script as a multi-line construct (above) or as a single line, eg:

```
awk 'BEGIN { found = 0 } $3 == "122e345a" { found = 1 } (found == 1) && $1 == "abc" { print $2 }' <file>
```

Using your sample files (`file1/file2/file3`), and adding `file4` as a copy of `file1` with the lines switched:

```
$ cat file4
abc 25b57790c
text xyz 122e345a rxyc

$ for f in file*
do
    echo "++++++++++++++ file : $f"
    awk 'BEGIN { found = 0 } $3 == "122e345a" { found = 1 } (found == 1) && $1 == "abc" { print $2 }' $f
done

++++++++++++++ file : file1
25b57790c
++++++++++++++ file : file2
++++++++++++++ file : file3
++++++++++++++ file : file4
```

Notice that while `file4` has lines that match both search strings, string `"122e345a"` shows up **after** string `"abc"`, which goes against one of the assumptions so `file4` fails our search.

Comment: @luxfred, I don't understand your comment; have you tried the code and if so, is it working or not working?

Comment: That doesn't seem to give me any result. 
But if I just try the awk script on all files, I have the result for all the files parsed after the matching one. the good result being excluded

Comment: $ for f in file*
do
    echo "++++++++++++++ file : $f"
    awk 'BEGIN { found = 0 } $3 ~ /122e345a/ { found = 1 } (found == 1) && $1 ~ /abc/ { print $2 }' $f
done

give no result,

but :
awk 'BEGIN { found = 0 } $3 ~ /122e345a/ { found = 1 } (found == 1) && $1 ~ /abc/ { print $2 }' *

shows:
b0894e35o
122e345a
....


Actually I have hundreds of files matching the same scheme.
When I pass the awk one on all commands, all the files before the matching one show nothing, but all the ones after, show field 2 after pattern abc
The correct file itself don't show anything

Comment: @luxfred What `awk` are you using on what system?

Comment: My `awk` solution works for a single file, thus the need for the looping construct; if you want to pass all files to a single `awk` invocation then I could re-work my answer but instead I'd suggest you see kusalanada's answer; I have no problems running my solution on cygwin, linux and solaris, so I'm in agreement with Kusalananda ... what version of `awk` are you running, ie, what does `awk --version` show?

Comment: # gawk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: I asked for your version of `awk`, not `gawk` ... we can't tell from what you've posted if your `awk` is a symlink to `gawk` or if your `awk` is some other version; on my SLES host `awk --version` also returns `GNU Awk 3.1.8` (`awk` is actually a symlink to `gawk`) and my code works; at this point I'd have to guess that your `awk` is 'broken' in which case you could try replacing `awk` with `gawk` to see if that works; while we're at it, might as well rule out a few other issues ... do any of these return anything: `alias awk` , `typeset -f | egrep awk`

Comment: @markp: Actually the system on which I am working is on solaris 11, The defautlt awk is too old and I almost never use it.   
The awk I am using is gawk which is a simlink to /usr/gnu/bin/awk and is GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: Strange, fact I try also on a linux machine with awk 4.0.1, there the script works if I  pass the files one by one, while if I try on all files I got the output for all files:

fred@odin ~/test $ awk 'BEGIN { found = 0 } $3 == "122e345a" { found = 1 } (found == 1) && $1 == "abc" { print $2 }' file*
25b57790c
b0894e35o
122e345a

awk 'BEGIN { found = 0 } $3 == "122e345a" { found = 1 } (found == 1) && $1 == "abc" { print $2 }' file3
awk 'BEGIN { found = 0 } $3 == "122e345a" { found = 1 } (found == 1) && $1 == "abc" { print $2 }' file1
25b57790c

Comment: @markp : I was always checking what I was doing wrong with my awk and missed the obvious, your assomption that the second pattern should be after the second  one, was what I missed.  
I corrected the files and it work with the for loop, but I i pass all the files It prints all the the result for all the files after the first patern is found

Comment: @luxfred - as I mentioned in an earlier comment, my answer only works for a single file at a time, hence the need for the loop; while I can update my answer with a multi-file solution, I'd recommend you first take a look at Kusalananda's answer which **does** handle multiple files, though his solution won't tell you which file generated which output (then again, your original question doesn't demonstrate what happens with matches in multiple files or if you need to know which file generated which output)